# How do I find and remove an email token from a string of emails in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, email-validation

I'm trying to standardize the email address in a field. Here are a couple examples of the problem I'm trying to solve:

```
ex 1 yyyyyyyy.xxxxxxxxx.p4elr874@carbuyingemail.com;yyyyyyyy.xxxxxxxxx.daojffab@carbuyingemail.com;xxxxxxxxx@aol.com
ex 2 xxxxxx51@gmail.com;yyyyyyyyy.xxxxxx.t78m45be@truecarcustomer.com;yyyyyyyyy.xxxxxx.dn4m9ujo@truecarcustomer.com
ex 3 3xxxxx996@anon.cargurus.com;xxxxxxxxxxx@comcast.net;3xx68xxxx@anon.cargurus.com;4xx2x3xxx@anon.cargurus.com
```

`
I'm trying to extract the usable email from the auto generated emails in strings similar to this, so for example in

(ex 1) I would want the @aol.com address;
in (ex 2) I would want the @gmail.com address;
in (ex 3) I would want the @comcast.net address.

I tried finding the charindex of the most popular service providers using a case statement, but since I don't how many chars exist before the @ symbol I'm at a loss about how to use the substring method.

There can be anywhere from 2 to 7 emails in a string. I know how to do it for 2. That was easy, but after that I have no idea. Here is what I have so far:

```
select email, len(email) - len(replace(email,';','')) num_semi
into #tmp1
from staging_transformations
where email != ''  
order by len(email) - len(replace(email,';','')) desc


select email,
case
    when num_semi = 1 then
        case
            when SUBSTRING(email,0,charindex(';',email)) like '%@anon.cargurus.com' then 
                case
                    when SUBSTRING(email,charindex(';',email) + 1,len(email)) like '%@anon.cargurus.com' then NULL
                    else SUBSTRING(email,charindex(';',email) + 1,len(email))
                end
            when SUBSTRING(email,0,charindex(';',email)) like '%@geico.zagdealer.com' then 
                case
                    when SUBSTRING(email,charindex(';',email) + 1,len(email)) like '%@geico.zagdealer.com' then NULL
                    else SUBSTRING(email,charindex(';',email) + 1,len(email))
                end
            when SUBSTRING(email,0,charindex(';',email)) like '%@truecarcustomer.com' then 
                case 
                    when SUBSTRING(email,charindex(';',email) + 1,len(email)) like '%@truecarcustomer.com' then NULL
                    else SUBSTRING(email,charindex(';',email) + 1,len(email))
                end
            when SUBSTRING(email,0,charindex(';',email)) like '%@carbuyingemail.com' then 
                case
                    when SUBSTRING(email,charindex(';',email) + 1,len(email)) like '%@carbuyingemail.com' then NULL
                    else SUBSTRING(email,charindex(';',email) + 1,len(email))
                end
            else SUBSTRING(email,0,charindex(';',email))
        end
    else email
end test,
num_semi
from #tmp1
```

I'm using T-SQL. Any suggestions?

Comment: if you use CHARINDEX to find the position of &comcast.net (for example) - then you take LEFT of the string up to that point - then you REVERSE the string and use CHARINDEX on that to find the ';' - then you take LEFT up to that point - then you have the EMAIL name part (but it is in reverse( so use REVERSE on that and join it back to &comcast.net - you might be best making a scalar function, where you can use variables and make a mini-program - I had to use ampersand in place of the AT character BTW due to this place

Comment: what is wrong with the other email address?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza They similar to auto-generated email addresses when you reply to a craigslist ad. As far as I know, those email addresses are "no reply" email addresses.

Comment: I mean why for (ex 1) you only want the @aol.com address? the other are valid email too.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Structure wise they are, but they are temp email addresses that are autogenerate.

Comment: so how you know the difference?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza because I have been investigating this problem for a while and determined which addresses are autogenerated and which ones are not for this particular data set or other sets from the same data sources.

Comment: ok, but how can we help you if you dont explain the logic rules?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Sorry, I didn't understand what you were asking. During my investigation I found that these emails are autogenerated and not worth holding on to: anon.cargurus.com, geico.zagdealer.com, truecarcustomer.com, carbuyingemail.com, and reply.craigslist.org.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I planned on first pulling the first valid email address token from the strings that matched the top 25 email addresses (ex. gmail.com, yahoo.com, hotmail.com, aol.com, msn.com, att.net, etc.). After I isolate those emails, I'm going to join it with the rest of the emails in the table and then check the structure of the email address with something like this `email like '%_@_%_.__%'`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I realize this is not perfect, but this is the quickest solution I could devise for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One better IMO way would be  to create a table with valid email addresses and then use [string split function](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)..(assuming email addresses are seperated by `;`

```
declare @string varchar(max)
set @string='yyyyyyyy.xxxxxxxxx.p4elr874@carbuyingemail.com;yyyyyyyy.xxxxxxxxx.daojffab@carbuyingemail.com;xxxxxxxxx@aol.com'


create table validemails
(
emailid varchar(50)
)

insert into validemails
select '@aol.com'

;with cte
as
(select * from 
[dbo].[SplitStrings_Numbers](@string,';') 
)
select * from cte c
cross apply
(
select * from validemails b where c.item like '%'+b.emailid+''
) d
```

Comment: They are split by semicolons